# How to apply an image style based on a condition (a date for ex.)?

Tags: rules, database

I'm looking for a way to apply a grayscale image style to a content type image field when certain conditions are met. A date is reached (date field) for example

Can the rules modules do this ?

Thanks for the suggestions & ideas

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with rules module with the help of [**Field formatter conditions**](https://drupal.org/project/ffc) module

> Adds conditions to field formatters. Configuration happens on the
>   "Manage Display" screens of every entity type on a per field basis
>   when clicking on the cogwheel on the right.

[image]

Supports

- Rules
- Field API fields
- Display Suite fields (only branch 2)

Simple conditions and actions

- Hide source field when target field is empty.
- Hide source field when target field is not empty.
- Hide source field when current user has specific roles.
- Hide source field on specific pages.
- Hide source field when target field contains a specific string.
- Hide source field when target field doesn't contain a specific string.
- Hide link field if title is empty.
- Hide date field if from/to has expired.

Rules actions

- Hide a field.
- Change image style.

Rules should always be a 'A field is rendered' event before they can be selected in the conditions dropdown on the "Manage Display" screens per field.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7 you can achieve it by creating a template file. Based on the your certain condition you can change the image style with **Desaturate Effect**.

Steps

- If you don't have the template file for a particular content type then, just create new template file inside your **active theme** `sites/all/themes/ACTIVE_THEME_NAME/templates/`. Just copy and paste **node.tpl.php** and rename it to **node--your_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME.tpl.php**.

  - For example to create an template file for an **ARTICLE CONTENT TYPE** rename to **node--article.tpl.php**.
- Now get the image field by printing the $node object. User **drupal_set_message()** to print the object with in PHP tags. You can print it after the **variables listing**

  ```
  <?php
   drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($node, 1) . "</pre>");
  ?>
  ```
- Add the grayscale image style using `admin/config/media/image-styles/add` with     **Desaturate Effect**.

  [image]
- After printing get the image field name

  - For this example Im using the field **field_image**.
- Based on your certain conditions change the image style and render the image using [**theme()**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7)

  [image]
- Now its time to render the image.

  [image]

Note

- In the custom template file you can go through the **available variables** at the top of the file.  And you can use the variable as per your requirement.
- Variable **$content** will have an array of node items.
- `print render($content);` will print all the node items. You can use `hide($content['field_name'])` to hide the specific field.
- You can also use `$node` object to add fields as per your requirement.

Comment: well, you explained about the implementation method, but not about the OP's question- "way to apply a grayscale image style to a content type image field when certain conditions are met"

Comment: Need to use **Desaturate effect** in the **image style**

Answer (score 0):

If a date is reached, then you want to change the image in to graycale, there is no need to use rules. Create two image presets using [ImageCache Actions](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions). Then print your image field in your node tpl according to your conditions:

```
<?php
  print theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => [STYLE NAME]));
?>
```