# How to apply an image style based on a condition?

Tags: commerce, rules, media

I've been following this discussion: [How to apply an image style based on a condition (a date for ex.)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96582/how-to-apply-an-image-style-based-on-a-condition-a-date-for-ex/163590#163590) but unfortunately it has not been a success.

I would like to have the image to change based on a boolean field type being checked or not. When I check the On Sale checkbox, I would like the product image to be displayed with a different image-style.

My boolean field is named field_commerce_saleprice_on_sale. 
1st image style is product_grid. 
2nd image style on_sale.
In node--product.tpl.php I found the line

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in template file, you can access your boolean variable using `$node` object. You can do following way :

```
if ($node->field_boolean[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) {
  print theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'style1_name'));
}
else {
  print theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'style2_name'));
}
```

**Or :**

If you are using `panels`, then you can use `visibility rule` to the fields by adding it twice with different image style.